# How to Incorporate a numerical prefactor into a radical in Maxima?

Tags: numerical, maxima

```
(%i2) x : expand(cosh(1)*sqrt(3+5*t));
(%o2)                        cosh(1) sqrt(5 t + 3)
(%i3) expand(float(x));
                                                     0.5
(%o3)                 1.543080634815244 (5.0 t + 3.0)
```

How can I get Maxima to incorporate the prefactor into the radical?  I'm looking for something that in this case yields something like

```
                                                   0.5
(%o3)                 (11.90548922 t + 7.143293537)
```

For numbers as small as these this is not a big deal, but for numerical evaluations Maxima tends to substitute rational approximations that may involve very large denominators, so that I end up with expressions where the prefactor is a very small number (like 6.35324353 × 10<sup>-23</sup>) and the numbers inside the square root are very large numbers (like 5212548545863256475196584785455844385452665612552468), so that it isn't obvious even what the order of magnitude of the result is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which uses pattern matching.

```
(%i1) matchdeclare (cc, numberp, [bb, aa], all) $
(%i2) defrule (r1f, cc*bb^0.5, foof(cc,bb));
                                0.5
(%o2)                   r1f : bb    cc -> foof(cc, bb)
(%i3) defrule (r2f, aa*cc*bb^0.5, aa*foof(cc,bb));
                                0.5
(%o3)                r2f : aa bb    cc -> aa foof(cc, bb)
(%i4) foof(a,b):= (expand(a^2*b))^0.5 $
(%i5) apply1 (1.543080634815244*(5.0*t + 3.0)^0.5, r1f, r2f);
                                                          0.5
(%o5)            (11.90548922770908 t + 7.143293536625449)
(%i6) apply1 (1.543080634815244*x*y*(5.0*t + 3.0)^0.5, r1f, r2f);
                                                        0.5
(%o6)          (11.90548922770908 t + 7.143293536625449)    x y
(%i7) apply1 (1/(1 + 345.43*(2.23e-2*u + 8.3e-4)^0.5), r1f, r2f);
                                      1
(%o7)            --------------------------------------------
                                                      0.5
                 (2660.87803327 u + 99.03716446700001)    + 1
```

It took some experimentation to figure out suitable rules `r1f` and `r2f`. Note that these rules match `...^0.5` but not `sqrt(...)` (i.e. exponent = 1/2 instead of 0.5). Of course if you want to match `sqrt(...)` you can create additional rules for that.

Not guaranteed to work for you -- a rule might match too much or too little. It's worth a try, anyway.